# Javascript calculating in for loops

Tags: javascript

I have a `<p id="rabbits">1 2 9 4</p>'` And i'm trying to calculate all the `1,2,9,4`

However, I'm stuck at this part:

```
var rabbits = $('#rabbits').text()
var rabbits_array = rabbits.split(/(\s+)/);
for (i in rabbits_array) {
     console.log(i) // prints 1,2,9,4
}
```

How do add all of these numbers together (which is 16 if you count manually) in javascript?

Comment: Ok, this should help: `let sum = 0; for (let r of rabbits_array) { sum += +r}; console.log(sum);`

Comment: Will you always be splitting the string on a space?

Comment: yes i will be always using space

Comment: Check my answer below. The way you're splitting it here with regex gives you an array like `['1', ' ', '2', ' ',...]` and those 'blank' spots will break the `parseInt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can map array to number and use reduce

```js
var rabbits = $('#rabbits').text()
  
var total = rabbits.split(" ").map(Number).reduce((a,c) => a + c)
                       
console.log(total)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="rabbits">1 2 9 4</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of ways to do this.

```
var rabbits = $('#rabbits').text()
var rabbits_array = rabbits.split(/(\s+)/);
var total = 0;

rabbits_array.forEach(function(element) {
    total += element * 1;
});

console.log(total);
```

You could use a standard for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < rabbits_array.length;i++) {
    total += rabbits_array[i] * 1;
}
```

You could replace the "multiply by 1" (which would have to validate beforehand that it's actually a number and not a letter), with `parseInt` or `parseFloat`.  Using these methods can do some of this validation for you, but may also give you odd results.

```
total += parseFloat(rabbits_array[i]);
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

There are other ways to do this as well, but these are just a few examples to get you going.  I'd suggest Googling "javascript loops" to read more about this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var rabbits = $('#rabbits').text()
var rabbits_array = rabbits.split(" ");
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < rabbits_array.length; i++) {
     total = total + parseInt(rabbits_array[i]);
}

console.log(total)
```

You need to convert the string version of the number (from your split function) to an actual number before adding them together

Comment: `i` is index... don't use `for in` on arrays